# Output displaying twice BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

When I try to execute the code, output value displayed twice. Is there any way to display it only once?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def powr(url):
  source_code = requests.get(url)
  plain_text = source_code.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
  for text in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'coin-page__price-number'}):
    head = text.string
    #print('Vertcoin =', head)
    print(head)

powr('https://coinranking.com/coin/power-ledger-powr')
```

Output:

```
0.695
0.695
```

Comment: Try using find instead of find_all

Comment: thank you so much. It worked :)

Comment: Fine, then i am adding an answer for future reference.  :-)

Comment: Sure. That would Great!

Comment: Put `break` just after print statement and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` in place of `findAll` solves the problem.

Of course you wouldn't need the loop anymore.
:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Easiest way to encounter this problem is to use return instead of print    at the end of your function.

def powr(url):
  source_code = requests.get(url)
  plain_text = source_code.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
  for text in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'coin-page__price-number'}):
    head = text.string
  return head

powr('https://coinranking.com/coin/power-ledger-powr')
```

Comment: You are essentially printing the last such text encountered by findAll. So traversing the entire loop would be an useless ordeal. Just returning the text in last index directly would be a good practice.